# If Else Statement in IBAction - iOS

Tags: ios, if-statement, ibaction

I have constructed `if-else` statement to make UIButtons act as a toggle before, but this set of code seems to be a little more challenging. I have 2 separate IBActions right now, one called open, the other called close. I would like to make it one IBAction that works as a toggle via an `if-else` statement. Here is the code for both IBActions.

```
- (IBAction)actionOpen:(id)sender {
    [self.flatDatePicker show];
}

- (IBAction)actionClose:(id)sender {
    [self.flatDatePicker dismiss];
}
```

Comment: Does `flatDatePicker` have any property that can expose its state, or can you add such a property? e.g. `if (self.flatDatePicker.visible) ...`?

Comment: Do you have the buttions linked via an `IBOutlet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a property or something, like this...

```
// in the private extension

@property (nonatomic) BOOL flatDatePickerOpen;
```

Then do something like this...

```
- (IBAction)toggleFlatDatePicker {
    if (self.flatDatPickerOpen) {
        [self.flatDatePicker dismiss];
        self.flatDatePickerOpen = NO;
    } else {
        [self.flatDatePicker show];
        self.flatDatePickerOpen = YES;
    }
}
```

You don't have to specify the sender part of the action either. If you're not using it then there's no need for it.

Alternatively, use a property on the flatDatePicker that tells you whether it is visible or not instead of the additional property.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create your own property for this, the flat picker already has one defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) BOOL        isOpen;                 // read only property, indicate in datepicker is open.
```

So...

```
- (IBAction)toggleFlatDatePicker {
    if (self.flatDatePicker.isOpen) {
        [self.flatDatePicker dismiss];
    }else{
        [self.flatDatePicker show];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BOOL` type in your header for `datePickerShowing`

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL datePickerShowing;
```

Synthesize it in your .m file

```
@synthesize datePickerShowing;
```

Set this to NO in your init method. `datePickerShowing = NO;`

In your IBAction:

```
if (datePickerShowing) {
    [flatDatePicker dismiss];
    datePickerShowing = NO;
} else {
    [flatDatePicker show];
    datePickerShowing = YES;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be synthesizing ivars manually like that anymore. Also, I wouldn't put anything in the header that isn't intended for external use.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine `self.flatDatePicker` is a `UIDatePicker` object, which inherits from `UIView`.  There is no need for a separate state flag, simply examine the [`UIView.hidden`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property:

```
- (IBAction)actionToggle:(id)sender {
    if (self.flatDatePicker.hidden)
        [self.flatDatePicker show];
    else
        [self.flatDatePicker dismiss];
}
```